# Mongo db taking too much RAM

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongodb for database. The size of all the databases is around 19G.

My RAM usage showing 64% of 2GB by mongod even when no query is being running.

As per FAQ saying

> MongoDB automatically uses all free memory on the machine as its cache. System resource monitors show that MongoDB uses a lot of memory, but its usage is dynamic. If another process suddenly needs half the server’s RAM, MongoDB will yield cached memory to the other process.

Is it because of that only or I am doing something wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB only allocates that memory but not use it all. It tells your system that other applications can use it whenever they need it. So if other applications  will ask for more memory then system will give it to them. You can check real memory usage in mongo shell. Check out mongo commands in documentation to learn more.